# Read and save data from file txt in a list with python code

Tags: python

This is my file.txt:

```
1,  AC233FA28A31,   -64,                            1.0741886104850389
1,  AC233FA28A32,   -67,                            4.990341223352587e+16
2,  AC233FA28A31,   -66,                            1.240560004316543
2,  AC233FA28A32,   -61,                            4190057960.7655835
3,  AC233FA28A31,   -64,                            1.0741886104850389
3,  AC233FA28A32,   -65,                            685898450406726.6
```

How can I read the third column and save the data in a List?

The output of Python code must be this list=[-64, -67, -66, -61, -64....]

Comment: Read the file line by line. The process each line as a string. You can probably us `split(,)`

Comment: Mannaggia a loro... why does people still send datas in .txt files instead of .json?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to make it understandable:

```
with open(r"file.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.readlines()

third_column = []
for line in data:
    value = line.split(",")[2].lstrip(" ")
    third_column.append(value)
    print(value)
```

First you read the lines of the file into an array `data`, then you iterate over each line, split the string by the character `,` with `line.split(",")`, select the 3rd element with `[2]`, strip the left side of the resulting string again by all spaces with `lstrip(" ")`, append the value to a list `third_column` as well as printing the value

Answer (score 3):

You can do that easily with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep='\s+', header=None)
res = df[2].tolist()
print(res)
```

And you will have your list saved in *res*.

Comment: Più che altro dubito sappia usare Pandas... Anyway if the OP does know how to use pandas, this is the best solution. +1

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r+') as file:
    # split in lines
    for line in file.read().split('\n'):
        # Parse the single lines
        riga = line.split(',')
        riga[0] = int(riga[0])
        riga[1] = riga[1].strip()
        riga[2] = int(riga[2])
        riga[3] = int(riga[3])
        lista.append(riga)
```

Otherwise, if you want to handle it as a dataframe, you should use `pandas` Python's library, as @Flavio suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `csv`.

```python
import csv

col1 = []
col2 = []
col3 = []

with open('file.txt') as f:
  for row in csv.reader(f):
    col1.append(row[0])
    col2.append(row[1])
    col3.append(float(row[2]))

print(col3)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to use the Pandas library you can use csv:

```py
with open("myfile.txt") as file:
         data= csv.reader(file)
         my_list = []
         for row in data:
             my_list.append(int(row[2].strip()))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use pandas and `read_csv`. Importantly, you should use `header=None` since no column names are available in the `file.txt`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.txt', header=None)

# if you really want a list
out = list(df[2].values)
```